# How to store the values which are entered in different text fields to the Server in objective C

Tags: objective-c, database

How to store the values which are entered in different text fields to the Server in objective C, In my project i have created the a form where it consists of different text fields where the user has to enter the values to the text field, i have kept one SAVE button, where after entering the values to the text field the user has to click the Save button.

I have to save the values entered in the text fields to the server on the click of the SAVE Button.

So how to save the data or values to the server on the click of the SAVE button.

The Following is the code i have used to create the form,

In .h File :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "PickerViewController.h"

@interface PopAppViewController : UIViewController < NumberPickedDelegate>{

UIPopoverController *popOverController;
    UIPopoverController *popOverControllerWithPicker;
    PickerViewController *pickerViewController;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtTest;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtSun;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtMon;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtTue;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtWed;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtThurs;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtFri;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtSat;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtTotal;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtTask;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtProject; 

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popOverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popOverControllerWithPicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) PickerViewController *pickerViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtTest;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtSun;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtMon;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtTue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtWed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtThurs;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtFri;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtSat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtTotal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtTask;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *txtProject;


-(IBAction)displayPickerPopover;
-(IBAction)exit;
-(IBAction)reset;
-(IBAction)save;
-(IBAction)total;


@end
```

In .m file :

```
#import "PopAppViewController.h"
//#import "TimeSheetDatabase.h"

@implementation PopAppViewController

@synthesize popOverController,popOverControllerWithPicker,pickerViewController,txtTest,txtSun,txtMon,txtTue,txtWed,txtThurs,txtFri,txtSat,txtTotal,txtTask,txtProject;




//-(id)initWithtxtProject:(NSString *)txtProject txtTask:(NSString *)txtTask txtSun:(int)txtSun txtMon:(int)txtMon txtTue:(int)txtTue txtWed:(int)txtWed txtThurs:(int)txtThurs txtFri:(int)txtFri txtSat:(int)txtSat txtTotal:(int)txtTotal{
//    
//    self=[super init];
//    if(self){
//        self.txtProject = txtProject;
//        self.txtTask = txtTask;
//        self.txtSun = txtSun;
//        self.txtMon = txtMon;
//        self.txtTue = txtTue;
//        self.txtWed = txtWed;
//        self.txtThurs = txtThurs;
//        self.txtFri = txtFri;
//        self.txtSat = txtSat;
//        self.txtTotal = txtTotal;
//        
//    }
//}


-(IBAction)displayPickerPopover {
    [txtTest resignFirstResponder];
    CGSize sizeOfPopover = CGSizeMake(300, 422);
    CGPoint positionOfPopover = CGPointMake(32, 325);
    [popOverControllerWithPicker presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(positionOfPopover.x, positionOfPopover.y, sizeOfPopover.width, sizeOfPopover.height)
                                                 inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)exit{

    exit(0);
}

-(IBAction)reset{

    txtSun.text = @"";
    txtMon.text = @"";
    txtTue.text = @"";
    txtWed.text = @"";
    txtThurs.text = @"";
    txtFri.text = @"";
    txtSat.text = @"";
    txtTotal.text = @"";
    txtTest.text = @"";
    txtTask.text = @"";
}

-(IBAction)save{



}


-(IBAction)total{

    int result = [txtSun.text intValue] + [txtMon.text intValue] + [txtTue.text intValue] + [txtWed.text intValue] + [txtThurs.text intValue] + [txtFri.text intValue] + [txtSat.text intValue];
    txtTotal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",result];

}




/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

-(void)numberDidChangeTo:(NSString *)newNumber {
    txtTest.text = newNumber;
}

-(void)didChangeSelection:(NSString *)newValue {
    txtTest.text = newValue;
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    pickerViewController = [[PickerViewController alloc] init];
    pickerViewController.delegate = self;
    popOverControllerWithPicker = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:pickerViewController];
    popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 216);

//    NSArray *timesheetinfo = [[TimeSheetDatabase database]getAllTimeSheet];
//    for(timesheetinfo *info in timesheetinfo){
//        
//        NSLog(@"%@ - %@ ",info.project,info.task);
//    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
}



// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {

    [popOverController release];
    [popOverControllerWithPicker release];
    [pickerViewController release];
    [txtTest release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the definition of "server" for you? Is it a Web Service, a database or do you want to store a xml file on a server? The answer to this question is impossible without knowing what you mean by server.

Comment: hi yan.kun, i want to store it in the mysql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile the data into a JSON string, and then send it to the server with an `NSURLRequest`

```
-(IBAction)save
{
  // build JSON string
  NSDictionary *postDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.txtTest.text, @"test",
                                                                            self.txtSun.text, @"sun",
                                                                            self.txtSun.text, @"mon",
                                                                            nil];
  NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:NULL];

  // perform http request (on a background thread)
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:@"http://example.com/save.php" cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

    // and now go back to the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSAutoreleasePool *mainQueuePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

      // debug: print response
      NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);

      // check for http error (this includes php exceptions)
      if ([urlResponse statusCode] != 200) {
        NSLog(@"save failed with status code != 200");
        return;
      }

      [mainQueuePool release];
    });

    [pool release];
  });
}
```

And in your php:

```
$rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");
$postData = json_decode($rawData);

print_r($postData);
```

Comment: What makes you think the server in question runs PHP?

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer and add the equivalent in other languages. I don't know how to read JSON data from POST in any language other than PHP.

Comment: Hi Abhi, i am trying to store the data to the local server like mamp through php,as looking to the video in the following link - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwCyaGoRNWM, but i am not getting how to add the php file to the project or where to write the php code in the project,i am new to the developing side,my question may look simple to you,please try to help me.

Answer (score 0):

As Objective-C supports pure C, you could use a C library like described [here](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/) to connect to a MySQL Server.